# Multiple cells per row in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there any way to have multiple cells per row in a uitableview using the uitableviewstylegrouped style? It exists in several of the official applications such as contacts but it could easily be a private API. If it is private has anybody found a good workaround?

[image]
<sub>(source: [meeu.me](http://meeu.me/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/contacts_sample.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Those apps also have a single cell per row. The image you link is in most likely a single custom cell that contains two UIButtons as subviews, or a footer view.